# Altering existing polyline shapefile that displays contour lines using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, line, contour

I have a polyline shapefile that displays contour lines. It has contour lines that have a interval of 10 m.

Is there any way to change the interval to 500 m in ArcGIS?

Comment: What is the required interval?

Comment: The required interval is 500 m.

Comment: Please **edit the question** in response to requests for clarification. The [Tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) explains how GIS SE is supposed to work. Please do not post thanks; the proper form of thanks is to upvote the answer.

Comment: Sorry. I will do that. As you may have guessed, I am new to GIS SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to select by attribute,

[image]

and use the following formula:

`MOD("Elevation",500)=0`

[image]

It will select every 500 meter from your contour line.

[image]

Please note that "Elevation" is the name of attribute field, so you may change it based on the correct name of the field used in your case.